# Why does NodeJS require me to use the full directory for downloaded modules?

Tags: node.js, directory, node-modules

For something like Express for example, which does not come with Node by default. I have to use `var express = require('C:/Users/User/node_modules/express');` instead of just `var express = require('express');`. I notice the modules which come by default such as http aren't in the same location as the ones I install. So what do I need to do in order to not have to write the whole directory. If it makes any difference I keep all my Node projects in `C:/Node/`, not the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you probably **don't have node modules installed locally**. For that you need a package.json file which you can get by running

> npm init

This will ask you some questions about your project and will set up node locally. A package.json file will be created which should look something like this (without dependencies).

```
{
  "name": "express-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "Link to your repository"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.3",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "yargs": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

You can then add the node modules you want by putting them in dependencies and running

> npm install

If you want to add node modules from commond line you can use

> npm install `package-name` --save